Can the baseball card collector problem be used to solve Rudrata/Hamiltonian Path? Asking for NP Complete proof
The baseball card collector problem is as follows:
Given packets P1,....., Pm each of which contains a subset of this year's baseball cards, is it possible to collect all the year's cards by buying at most k packets?
For example, if the players are {Ozuna, Freeman, Morton, Sandoval} and the packets are { {Ozuna, Freeman}, {Freeman, Morton}, {Sandoval}, {Freeman, Sandoval} }, there does not exist a solution for k=2, but there does for k=3 such as {Ozuna, Freeman}, {Freeman, Morton}, {Sandoval}.
Prove that this problem is NP-Complete.
Your input is the packets P1,....,Pm the set of this year's players and an integer k > 0. Your output is the subset of at most k packets that can be used to collect every player, or report NO if no subset exists.
Can I use Rudrata Path or Rudrata Cycle -> baseball card for the proof?
My attempt:
BCCP is in the class NP because it's a search problem and we can verify the solution in O(mn^2) time, each subset can have at most n cards, takes at worst O(n) to check off each card in some helper boolean hash set P with all players, there are m sets to iterate through.
Rudrata Path input to BCCP:
Take G(V, E), create set {s, t} for every edge (u, v) in G, pass in set of sets as P1...Pm. Pass in set of all vertices as P, pass number of vertices - 1 as k.
Output transformation:
If BCCP returns no, return no for Rudrata. If BCCP returns yes, return the path which is guaranteed to connect all vertices with no cycles as the solution to Rudrata
The only problem is what do we do about the constraint of starting vertex s and destination vertex t in the original input? Another idea is to use Rudrata cycle instead of path. The input/output transformations would be the same except the number of vertices V instead of V-1 is passed in as k to BCCP. This guarantees a simple cycle with exactly V edges if one is found and we don't need to worry about the starting/ending node.
IFF proof:
This should be straightforward if the source/destination node problem is solved. BCCP solution is guaranteed to be a minimum spanning tree if k is set to V-1. If there is a solution to BCCP there is a solution to Rudrata, if there is no solution to BCCP there is no solution to Rudrata, etc.

Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source of all text that was originally written by others or copied from other sources?

Your construction is not very clear. Please add details for the construction of the reduction from Rudrata to BCCP.

which part is unclear?

For example "pass in set of sets as P1...Pm": what does that mean? What is $m$? What is $P_i$? Be more precise.

I'm transforming the input of Rudrata path to BCCP, P1...Pm is part of the input to BCCP as defined in the first sentence of the problem: "Given packets P1,....., Pm each of which contains a subset of this year's baseball cards." I'm passing in the sets that were built from the edges of graph G, which is part of the input to Rudrata. All of this stated in the OP. P_i is the ith packet in the set P1 to Pm, I don't think this needs to be clarified.

I understand what $P_i$ is and what $m$ is given an input of BCCP. What is unclear is how you construct $P_i$ given an input of Rudrata, and what is $m$ given the input of Rudrata.

m is the number of edges in G, every edge is turned into a subset/packet of cards in the BCCP input. The details can be whatever you like. We can map the vertex labels in G to baseball player names and vice versa so each lookup takes O(1) and the construction of both arrays take O(n). For each edge (x, y) in G we construct set {a, b}

edit the question itself to clarify your responses to the comments, giving credit where necessary.

As far as I understand you could reduce edge cover problem to BCCP this way rather than Hamiltonian cycle problem

Also if you are not limited for reduction from Hamiltonian cycle problem, you may just find essentially the same problem in Karp's list of 21 $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problems
